# How can I get a WebSphere project to run under tc server?

Tags: java, spring, websphere

Just wondering if anyone has ever converted a Websphere project to run under tc server?  I run on a Mac and would love to be able to run my application locally without having to run Websphere in a VM.

I realize there are differences which would have to be accounted for, and that's really my question - what would I have to change?  I also realize that even if this is possible, one couldn't depend on the tc server configuration before going to production - it would have to be tested in Websphere first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know, application server provides lot more features than a tomcat.  Hence first, you would have to check if your application is using any of those features.  If so, then you would have to see if that missing functionality could be plugged-in somehow.  To exemplify, you could be using the transactional capability of the application server.  Tomcat doesn't come with transaction capability.  You would need to plug-in a a third party component for that.  For this to happen less intrusively, the code should be configurable so that based on the environment it would know whether to make use of the capabilities of the application server or use the capabilities of the plugged-in components in case of tomcat.

**Advantage of this:** It would certainly be boosting to the productivity if you use tomcat to develop rather than any application server, as the time it takes to start and stop tomcat if far less than the coffee time (To me ,one coffee time is the amount it takes for an application server to stop and start even when you have the minimal hardware requirements mentioned by it)

**Warning:**: Again this approach has a negative point that you would miss to see how your component interacts with the classes in the production environment, while you develop.  Hence it becomes mandatory to have your QA environment and above to make use of the application server.  This way you could avoid any surprises in production.

Comment: Yeah, we have a shared dev and stage environment that both use WAS.  However, deploying to those environments is pretty tedious, thus the desire to run the app via Tomcat locally.  I don't think we use any WAS-specific features.  The other benefit you didn't mention is that I'd avoid WAS' 8-million clicks to deploy admin console. :)  Thanks for the input.